# How to add -Xlint:unchecked option or any javac option in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, database, eclipse

How can i to add -Xlint:unchecked option or any javac option in Eclipse?
this is strange there is no obvious way to do that in eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

First, go to the Preferences window. If you're running Windows or Linux, it'll be under the 'Window' menu, if you're using Mac OSX it'll be under the 'Eclipse' menu. Then go to `Java -> Compiler -> Errors / Warnings -> Generic Types` and you'll see three options for compiler warnings / errors on unchecked types and operations. Chang them from error or warning to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse does not use the javac compiler - it has [its own compiler](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

-Xlint:unchecked is set to warning by default in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing builds with ant in Eclipse (as I was today), then it's really not a setting in Eclipse but an additional setting/flag(?) on the `javac` task.

Found via Darins' helpful hint [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/82724/):

> Specifically compilerarg nested element.

Here's how to add it, found on the Apache javac task [page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
     destdir="${classes.dir}"
     classpathref="libraries">
   <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
</javac>
```

Hope this helps someone else, as I didn't quite get it at first myself.